# Proof $\limsup_{n\to\infty}\max\{a_n,b_n\} =\max\{\limsup_{n\to\infty} a_{n}, \limsup_{n\to\infty} b_{n}\}$

Tags: real-analysis

If you are given that $(a_n)$ and $(b_n)$ are bounded sequences (so they don't need to converges). If you make $c_n = \max\{a_n,b_n\}$, proof:

$$\limsup_{n\to\infty} c_n = \max\{\limsup_{n\to\infty} a_{n}, \limsup_{n\to\infty} b_{n}\}$$

I already know that: $\lim_{n\to\infty} c_n = \max\{\lim_{n\to\infty} a_{n}, \lim_{n\to\infty} b_{n}\}$, but I just can't figure out how to proof it when there are suprema. Can somebody help me?

Comment: Hint: Since you have bounded sequences, you can find convergent subsequences.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Prove $\leq$ and $\geq$. Since $a_n,b_n\leq c_n$, you can immediately prove $\geq$. For $\leq$, let $c_{n_k}$ be the subequence which converges to the supremum $C=\limsup_n c_n$. Then $c_{n_k}$ must have infinitely many terms of $a_i$ or $b_i$. WLOG suppose it's $a_i$. Take a further subsequence of $c_{n_k}$ along these $a_i$, which must again converge to $C$. But then $C\leq \limsup_na_n$. Repeat the argument for infinitely many $b_n$ and the conclusion follows.